# Dropping DNS connection via iptables for testing

Tags: iptables

I am trying to monitor behaviour of simple TV set-top box while losing connection to one or other DNS. The box is behind simple linux machine with debian which is then connected to network with DHCP and such. I am trying to use the middle-machine as traffic filter, so I can see if the set-top box switch easily to second DNS after losing connection with current.

When I am trying to DROP connection via iptables on the linux machine, banning IP of DNS, which is then unpingable from the machine (proving iptables config takes effect], the set-top box is still able to use the DNS normally. Monitoring the traffic using tcpdump proves it. Set-top box itself is obtaining all the info from network. The purpose is to simulate possible full or partial DNS failure in real envirnoment.

```
Using variations of: (OUTPUT, -d)
iptables -A INPUT -s 212.X.X.X -j DROP
even (OUTPUT)
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

I am not sure what I am missing here (and I certainly do). I was also specifying interface facing network and such

Answer (score 3):

The `INPUT` chain in IPTables acts on traffic whose destination is the computer running IPTables. It does not affect forwarded traffic.

You need to use the `FORWARD` chain for packets that go through the computer and that are not directed to it.

For example:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d <destinationIP> -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

This rule drops all UDP packets from 192.168.0.0/24 network to  port 53.